# How to discard changes that came from an already-merged Git branch?

Tags: git, branch

I have two branches: Master and "Test". I've made few changes to my code, while on Test branch. Later on, I've merged the two branches together, and kept working on the Master branch.

Now, i would like to completely discard all changes made to my code, from the Test branch, without impacting the changes that were made later, on the master branch.

Basically, i want to tell Git: "get rid of anything that came from test branch, but leave all the rest alone".

Is it even possible to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is called git revert. I'll link to dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Git Revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032296/how-to-use-git-revert)

Comment: Additional docu: http://schacon.github.io/git/git-revert.html

Comment: Ignore my earlier comments - if the changes were merged into master, then revert is the correct approach.