# How to revert a commit as a new commit in a branch

Tags: git, github

Basically I have the scenario that I have a commit on the `master` which I want to revert to the previous state to commit new changes.
The whole thing should be done in a branch, so my idea was to branch the master with the unwanted commit to a new branch `b`, then revert the unwanted commit `unwantedC` in my branch `b` and push it as a new commit `revertedUnwantedC`. My goal ist that I don't get a status like "your branch is xy commits behind master", because my branch should be ahead then. If that is possible I want to push my desired changes `newCommit` in the branch and then make a PR that doesn't complain about merge problems with the master because he thinks that the master is ahead. Is something like that possible ? And what commands would I have to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, what you describe should be easily possible. Consider the following history:

```
A-B-C-D-E <- master
```

Now, `C` is the faulty commit that you want to revert (and then further build upon that reverted state):

```
$ git checkout -b unwanted C
```

You are now on a new branch called `unwanted` which contains your faulty commit and everything before (but nothing after).

```
A-B-C-D-E <- master
    ^--      unwanted
```

Now, revert C (will create a new commit on your branch) and keep working:

```
$ git revert C
# hack hack hack
$ git commit
# hack hack hack
$ git commit
```

gives you (`C'` being the revert of commit `C`):

```
A-B-C-D-E    <- master
     \
      C'-X-Y <- unwanted
```

You can then push and create a pull request/merge request or simply merge `unwanted` back into `master`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge unwanted
```

Note that after the merge any changes of `C` will no longer exist in master (they have been reverted and merging also merges these *reverse changes*).

Comment: Thank for you reply, i tried what you wrote, but once i try to revert the unwanted `c` i face the problem that the commit is a merge commit and `is a merge but no -m option was given.` can you explain what i would have to do ? Tbh i don't get what the mainline  (-m) switch is doing

Comment: The mainline switch tells Git which side of a merge to keep and which to discard. When you have a commit "Merge branch B into master" then running `git revert -m 1` will revert changes of `B` and keep `master`. Passing `-m 2` will revert changes of `master` and keep `B`. Read [How to revert a faulty merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) in the Git documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) command to create a new commit that undoes a previous commit. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032296/how-to-use-git-revert) goes into more detail on how it works.

When you merge your branch with the new commit back into `master` you'll have one commit that makes the change and another commit that undoes that change.